# Как обеспечить передачу данных между двумя устройствами с разными IP

Tags: сеть, ip, маршрутизатор

Есть два устройства, они имею разные ip адреса. Необходимо сделать так, что они могли передавать данные друг с другом. Как это можно реализовать, с помощью каких устройств? Возможно с помощью маршрутизатора - подключить оба устройства к нему?

Comment: Дайте больше подробностей. Откуда взялись ip адреса, к чему сейчас подключены устройства. А так то достаточно просто куска кабеля между устройствами, что бы они могли друг с другом общаться, оборудование не требуется. Если конечно ip и маски верно установлены